# Force Wi-Fi to stay on

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

Is there any way you can force Wi-Fi to stay active with lockscreen ?
I've noticed that the phone disconnects from the Wi-Fi network when it goes to the lockscreen,
but I need it to stay active..

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that there is no way to change that (saving battery power).

The only thing you can do is to plug in your Windows Phone in order to keep your Wi-Fi active in lockscreen mode.

Maybe a  future update could add an option to let the user chooses if he wants WiFi on or not when it goes to the lockscreen.